# not updating entity in viewmodel after post request using ajax

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I am new to knockout.js and i am using post method to update data into database . Here is my code

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SProduct.aspx.cs" Inherits="SProduct" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="body">
        <h2>
            Knockout CRUD Operations with ASP.Net Form App</h2>
        <h3>
            List of Products</h3>
        <table id="products1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Category
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Price
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Actions
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Products">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: Id">
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Name">
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Category">
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: formatCurrency(Price)">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button data-bind="click: $root.edit">
                            Edit</button>
                        <button data-bind="click: $root.delete">
                            Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Total :
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: formatCurrency($root.Total())">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <br />
        <div style="border-top: solid 2px #282828; width: 430px; height: 10px">
        </div>
        <div data-bind="if: Product">
            <div>
                <h2>
                    Update Product</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="productId" data-bind="visible: false">
                    ID</label>
                <label data-bind="text: Product().Id, visible: false">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="name">
                    Name</label>
                <input data-bind="value: Product().Name" type="text" title="Name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="category">
                    Category</label>
                <input data-bind="value: Product().Category" type="text" title="Category" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="price">
                    Price</label>
                <input data-bind="value: Product().Price" type="text" title="Price" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.update">
                    Update</button>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.cancel">
                    Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="ifnot: Product()">
            <div>
                <h2>
                    Add New Product</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="name">
                    Name</label>
                <input data-bind="value: $root.Name" type="text" title="Name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="category">
                    Category</label>
                <input data-bind="value: $root.Category" type="text" title="Category" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="price">
                    Price</label>
                <input data-bind="value: $root.Price" type="text" title="Price" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.create">
                    Save</button>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.reset">
                    Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function formatCurrency(value) {
            return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
        }

        function ProductViewModel() {

            //Make the self as 'this' reference
            var self = this;
            //Declare observable which will be bind with UI 
            self.Id = ko.observable("");
            self.Name = ko.observable("");
            self.Price = ko.observable("");
            self.Category = ko.observable("");

            var Product = {
                Id: self.Id,
                Name: self.Name,
                Price: self.Price,
                Category: self.Category
            };

            self.Product = ko.observable();
            self.Products = ko.observableArray(); // Contains the list of products

            // Initialize the view-model
            $.ajax({
                url: 'SProduct.aspx/GetAllProducts',
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    // debugger;

                    $.each(data.d, function (index, prd) {

                        self.Products.push(prd);
                    })
                    //Put the response in ObservableArray
                }
            });

            // Calculate Total of Price After Initialization
            self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
                var sum = 0;
                var arr = self.Products();
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    sum += arr[i].Price;
                }
                return sum;
            });

            //Add New Item
            self.create = function () {
            Product.Id="333";
                if (Product.Name() != "" && Product.Price() != "" && Product.Category() != "") {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'SProduct.aspx/Add',
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data:"{item:" + ko.toJSON(Product) + "}",
                        success: function (data) {
                                 self.Products.push(data.d);


                            self.Name("");
                            self.Price("");
                            self.Category("");

                        },
                        error:function(data)
                        {
                        alert("error");
                        console.log(data.d);
                        }
                    });

                }
                else {
                    alert('Please Enter All the Values !!');
                }

            }
                         //Delete product details
                         self.delete = function (Product) {
                         if (confirm('Are you sure to Delete "' + Product.Name + '" product ??')) {
                         var id = Product.Id;

                         $.ajax({
                         url:  'SProduct.aspx/Delete',
                         cache: false,
                         type: 'POST',
                         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                         data:"{id:" +  ko.toJSON(id) + "}",
                         success: function (data) {
                         self.Products.remove(Product);

                         },
                         error:function(data){
                         console.log(data.d);
                        alert('Error');
                         }
                         })
                         }
              }

            // Edit product details
            self.edit = function (Product) {
                self.Product(Product);

            }

            // Update product details
            self.update = function () {
                var Product = self.Product();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'SProduct.aspx/Update',
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data:"{Product:" +  ko.toJSON(Product) + "}", 
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                        console.log(data.d);

//                        self.Products.removeAll();
                        //   self.Products(data.d); //Put the response in ObservableArray

                        self.Product(null);

                        alert("Record Updated Successfully");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                })

            }

            // Reset product details
            self.reset = function () {
                self.Name("");
                self.Price("");
                self.Category("");
            }

            // Cancel product details
            self.cancel = function () {
                self.Product(null);

            }
        }
        var viewModel = new ProductViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Updated**
[image]
Here is screen shot of my page . when i click on update ajax success function is called, but no change in above table field .

Comment: You are returning one `Product` from your `Update` so it does not return a list. Just remove the `self.Products.removeAll();                        self.Products(data.d);` lines completely from the success method if you viewmodels are wired correctly it is enough to null out the `Poduct` property.

Comment: but it will not change the updated value in a table which is just above that form .

Comment: @nemesv check please question update .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have to update the item back to the list? You're not doing anything to the properties of the object on the server side are you?

Your edit method should look something like this:

```
    self.edit = function(item) {
        self.Product(item);

    };
```

and remove the following code nemesv said.

```
   self.Products.removeAll();
   self.Products(data.d); //Put the response in ObservableArray
```

My first post so be gentle ;)

### Response to comment:

change your success to:

```
    success: function (data) {
          var product = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Products(), function(item) {
               return (item.Id == data.d.Id);       
          });  // You could either update the product object with the new values from data.d or delete it and add a new product object.
          for (var p in product ) {
                product [p] = data.d[p];
          } 

          self.Product(null);
          alert("Record Updated Successfully");
    },
```

Found a bug, it was replacing the observables with native values.

```
          for (var p in product ) {
                product [p](data.d[p]);
          }
```

I took the liberty of simplifying the code and removing everything that hasn't anything to do with the update function. The following code example should work. ( I used knockout 2.3.0 and jQuery 1.9.1)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function Product(id, name, price, category) {
        var self = this;
        self.Id = ko.observable(id);
        self.Name = ko.observable(name);
        self.Price = ko.observable(price);
        self.Category = ko.observable(category);
    }

    function ProductViewModel() {

        var self = this;
        self.Product = ko.observable();
        self.Products = ko.observableArray(); // Contains the list of products

        $.ajax({
            url: 'SProduct.aspx/GetAllProducts',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.d, function (index, prd) {
                    var p = new Product(prd.Id, prd.Name, prd.Price, prd.Category);
                    self.Products.push(p);
                });
            }
        });

        self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            var arr = self.Products();
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                sum += arr[i].Price;
            }
            return sum;
        });

        self.edit = function(product) {
            self.Product(product);
        };

        self.update = function() {
            var product = self.Product();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'SProduct.aspx/Update',
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: "{product:" + ko.toJSON(product) + "}",
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var p in product) {
                        product[p](data.d[p]);
                    }
                    self.Product(null);
                    alert("Record Updated Successfully");
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        };

        self.reset = function() {
            self.Name("");
            self.Price("");
            self.Category("");
        };

        self.cancel = function() {
            self.Product(null);

        };
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var viewModel = new ProductViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });


</script>
```

Comment: :) i am updating the properties on server side and its working. the problem is its not populating with changed properties.

Comment: still no change in the table which is just above the update form . update value show after i refresh the page manually.

Comment: i have also update my question with screen shot . where you can see that when i click on update value are changed in db but that table still show old value.

Comment: Are your properties in the Product object observables?

Comment: Think i found the reason. Look at the bottom of my post.

Comment: I am new to knockout so not getting what you want to ask but i have pasted complete HTML of that page. GetAllProduct,Add,Delete working perfectly just facing issue with Update which is updating value in database successfully but html table its not show updated one .

Comment: product [p](data.d[p]);   is not a function ?

Comment: Response updated. I think the main problem is that when you're adding the objects to the self.Products observablearray you're just adding a anonymous object without any observable properties.